# git commit not showing up in github

Tags: git, github

I am git newbee and I have a very simple github repo and I want to commit a change to it, so I do this ...

1) start "Git Bash" (I am on a Windows system)
2) execute ...

```
$ git clone https://github.com/redcricket/simple_flashlight.git
```

3) Export my change from eclipse to simple_flashlight/flashlight/
4) cd into that ...

```
$ cd simple_flashlight/flashlight/
```

5) Do a diff ...

```
$ git diff AndroidManifest.xml
diff --git a/flashlight/AndroidManifest.xml b/flashlight/AndroidManifest.xml
index a57b2c1..59d5fc5 100644
--- a/flashlight/AndroidManifest.xml
+++ b/flashlight/AndroidManifest.xml
@@ -4,6 +4,7 @@
       android:versionCode="1"
       android:versionName="1.0">
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
+
<!-- Allows access to the flashlight -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
@@ -16,7 +17,12 @@


     <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
+    <!--
+      - to prevent "flashing" when orientation changes I added the line
+      - android:configChanges="orientation"
+      -->
         <activity android:name=".FlashlightActivity"
+                         android:configChanges="orientation"
                   android:label="@string/app_name">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in flashlight/AndroidManifest.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

6) I do the "staging" ... I think ... by doing this ...

```
$ git add AndroidManifest.xml
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in flashlight/AndroidManifest.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
$ git status
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in flashlight/AndroidManifest.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   AndroidManifest.xml
#
```

7) do my commit like so ...

```
$ git commit -m "do not flash light on orientation change"
[master warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in flashlight/AndroidManifest.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
361f69b] do not flash light on orientation change
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in flashlight/AndroidManifest.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
1 file changed, 6 insertions(+)
```

Then I go look at my repo in https://github.com/redcricket/simple_flashlight/commits/master
and I do not see my changes.  I here's my git config ...

```
$ git config --global -l
user.name=redcricket
user.email=red.cricket.blog@gmail.com
```

... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You committed that change to the **local** clone of the repository.

If you want to see that commit on GitHub, you'll need to `git push` it there first.

Comment: awesome! Thanks ... now if I can just remember my password :)