# Cloning a github repository

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have a GitHub repository that I would regularly access and update from my laptop, but recently I got a desktop and I would like to be able to update the repository from both computers. So I downloaded GitHub Desktop onto my desktop and cloned my repository via the "Create, clone or add a local repository" button in the top left corner and entered my username and password when prompted. That's were the problems began.

First of all, the repository that was downloaded was a 4-month-old version of my repository, so it didn't have any changes that were made after that time. Secondly, whenever I tried to sync it, it wouldn't affect my repository when I opened it in chrome.

I don't really know much about how GitHub repositories work and only use one as a free website/cloud; so I apologize if the answer to my question is obvious.

What did I do terribly wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: When is the last time you pushed from your laptop, and are you sure that your laptop has been pointing to the same repo you cloned on your desktop?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, what do you mean by 'pushed'? The last time it was synced was about a week ago. Also, I only have 1 repository, so unless I did something terribly wrong it should be pointing to the same one...

Comment: This is very basic.  `git push` is something you need to do in order for your GitHub repo to receive the changes you have committed locally.

Comment: When you view your work in GitHub, can you see that it was updated recently?

Comment: @tripleee, so is it the same as sync? If it yes, why bother opening up the shell if one could simply press a button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git commit not showing up in github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800874/git-commit-not-showing-up-in-github)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, when I view my repo on github.com I see my repository the way it was 4 months ago. However, if I go directly to my page I see the week-old version.... what could that mean??

Comment: What is "my page?"  And what is GitHub?  You haven't been pushing your data and you should do so immediately to avoid catastrophic loss.

Comment: Can you list all branches and verify that you are looking at the same branches?